# filter an object key:val in vue

Tags: vue.js, object, filter

I have an object with key:val I want to filter the object by value like "ג6"
how i do that? I dont have alias name for search
this is the object

```
specialityTest={ 
 "4969": "ג6",
 "4973": "ג19",
 "5163": "ה",
 "5165": "ה1",
 "5200": "ה2", 
"5486": "גן1" 
}
```

I want to do

```
 this.nurseListSpeciality2 = this.specialityTest.filter((el) => {
    return el.value == "fffff";
  });
```

I get an error:

> this.specialityTest.filter is not a function

how can I filter this object?

Comment: show the full code, specialityTest !== this.specialityTest also the object is not an array so you cant loop over it with filter on its own, plus .value is not a key

Comment: What is actual goal ? Why do want filter an object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` for filtering your keys where the values match.

```js
this.nurseListSpeciality2 = Object.keys(this.specialityTest).filter((val) => this.specialityTest[val] === "ג6");
```

Finally, when rendering you can loop over the array of keys that will be returned and the render values associated with those keys

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="val in nurseListSpeciality2" :key="val">
      {{ specialityTest[val] }}
    </li>
</ul>
```